# Cannot convert UIImage to NSData when fetched with PhotoKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, photokit

My scenario is that I select one of the photos fetched from system album with PhotoKit and presented in my `UICollectionView` and pass the selected photo (`UIImage`) to my next `UIView` and send it to remote server in form of `NSData`.
But when I put breakpoint before sending to track the `NSData` I found that the `UIImage` had data with allocated memory while `NSData` did not.

Here is the code to fetch the `UIImage` (Please notice that I didn't specify any `PHImageRequestOptions` object):

```
NSMutableArray *images = @[].mutableCopy;
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
PHAsset *asset = _photoPickerCollectionView.pickedAsset;
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(asset.pixelWidth*0.5, asset.pixelHeight*0.5);
[manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:targetSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
    _nextView.pickedOne = result;
}];
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I convert the `UIImage` to `NSData` like this:

```
UIImage *image = _pickedOne;
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, imageQuality);
```

When I tracked the variables, the `UIImage` contains data as below:

[image]

But the `NSData` is `nil` as below:

[image]

And what was ODD is that if I specified an `PHImageRequestOptions` object for the `PHImageManager` to request images, the `NSData` wouldn't be `nil`. I'm not sure what was changed with or without the `PHImageRequestOptions` and why it would make such difference.

UPDATE:
What I found is that if you specify `PHImageRequestOptions` to `nil` then the default options will force it to fetch photos asynchronously which, in my opinion, can be unstable for `NSData`, so when I specify `options.synchronous = YES;` it would work.

But in this case, would it cause any retain cycle or some `PhotoKit` objects won't get released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method by default is asynchronous. You need to set options to explicitly make the image fetching synchronous. My strong suggestion for such kind of conversion is to use this API:

```
- (PHImageRequestID)requestImageDataForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset options:(nullable PHImageRequestOptions *)options resultHandler:(void(^)(NSData *__nullable imageData, NSString *__nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *__nullable info))resultHandler;
```

This returns you the data directly but you will have to make this synchronous as well. This WON'T cause any retain cycles for any objects. 
Hope this helps. :)